# Fetch the difference in result in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables `table_one` and `table_two`.

`table_one` has incomplete records while `table_two` has all records

I want to fetch the difference in each date `id_date`, however i cant get results in a date where there is no record to join

```
SELECT   
  ID_DATE, 
  CODE, 
  RATE, 
  SUM(PURCHASES), 
  sum(COMMISSION)
FROM ( 
SELECT 
  A.ID_DATE, 
  A.CODE, 
  A.RATE, 
  (B.PURCHASES - A.PURCHASES) PURCHASES, 
  (B.COMMISSION - A.COMMISSION) COMMISSION
FROM (SELECT * FROM  TABLE_ONE WHERE   ID_DATE BETWEEN  20201101 AND 20201130 ) A LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT  *  FROM TABLE_TWO WHERE   ID_DATE BETWEEN  20201101  AND 20201130 ) B 
ON A.ID_DATE  = B.ID_DATE AND   A.CODE = B.CODE AND A.RATE = B.RATE
)  GROUP BY ID_DATE, CODE, RATE
```

Link to my fiddle for test  [click here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=ca4cd323bfd13afc9fd24c3e887c1d46)

I cant get records of id_date 20201111 for example

Comment: I'd try `coalesce(B.PURCHASES, 0)` etc to avoid null issues-

Comment: Why not a RIGHT JOIN? (If table_two is complete.)

Comment: @jarlh i will add that,

Comment: In answer to your [deleted question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66134453/1509264) you can use [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=01c53605ffcd476f6cfc2720605c633a).

Comment: @MT0 I have undeleted, after editing. post to answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
select t2.id_date, t2.code, t2.rate,
    sum(t2.purchases - coalesce(t1.purchases, 0)) as purchases,
    sum(t2.commission - coalesce(t1.commission, 0)) as commission
from table_two t2
left join table_one t1 on t2.id_date = t1.id_date and t2.code = t1.code and t2.rate = t1.rate
where t2.id_date between 20201101 and 20201130
group by t2.id_date, t2.code, t2.rate
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use proper join and it can be achieved using the following query:

```
SELECT B.ID_DATE,
       B.CODE,
       B.RATE,
       SUM(B.PURCHASES - COALESCE(A.PURCHASES,0)) PURCHASES,
       SUM(B.COMMISSION - COALESCE(A.COMMISSION,0)) COMMISSION
  FROM TABLE_TWO   B
  LEFT JOIN TABLE_ONE   A
ON A.ID_DATE = B.ID_DATE
   AND A.CODE = B.CODE
   AND A.RATE = B.RATE
   AND A.ID_DATE BETWEEN 20201101 AND 20201130
 WHERE B.ID_DATE BETWEEN 20201101 AND 20201130
 GROUP BY B.ID_DATE,
          B.CODE,
          B.RATE
ORDER BY ID_DATE
```

[**db<>fiddle demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=3c178b8a40609777d018c4df08bbcfaa)